# PHP: how to retrieve form ID from Wordpress' built-in forms

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way that I, using PHP, can retrieve WP's built-in form shortcode (picture)?

[image]

I have tried `do_shortcode()` and googled but haven't found anything.

Why do I ask?
Because the website that I "inherited" at work uses a custom WP theme that is built with a framework created by the developers who made the website (external consultants). The framework stopped "existing", we're unable to contact the developers - and there's no documentation about said framework whatsoever. My knowledge of PHP is not good enough to understand the complexity of this site, and I need a workaround for something form-related while I wrap my head around the framework.

Comment: `do_shortcode()` is what you need. Note that it *returns* the evaluated string, are you ***echo***ing that result?

Comment: Hi @George this is what I'm doing: `echo do_shortcode('[form-ID]');` and the result is "form-ID". I'm not sure what the variable/entity/element/thingie that stores the form ID is called, so I dunno what to write within the method.

Comment: You need to pass the shortcode exactly as you see it there, I.E. `echo do_shortcode( '[form id="9458"]' );`

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thanks @George